# Set Current Network Type

Tags: android, android-networking

Good afternoon guys, I have a problem with Android.
I can get the current state of the data network with `getNetworkType()`, but
How can I set the current state of the data network ?

thank you all, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: you want to identify what type of network you have?? what do you mean by "How can I set the current state of the data network"?

Comment: I don't want to identify what type of network I have. I want to switch on 4G network with a button while I am using 3G network.I hope to have been clear

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to set it manually. Why would you need this?

If you meant 'check if mobile data transmitting is on', you can use this:

```
public boolean systemMobileStatusIsOn()
{
    try {
        Class cmClass = Class.forName(cm.getClass().getName());
        Method method = cmClass.getDeclaredMethod("getMobileDataEnabled");
        method.setAccessible(true); // Make the method callable
        // get the setting for "mobile data"
        return (Boolean)method.invoke(cm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Some problem accessible private API
        // TODO do whatever error handling you want here
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but I don't want check if mobile data transmitting is on.